# Laravel 5.2 Model Structure

Tags: model, laravel-5

I am trying to osrt out a legacy db and getting totally confused.

I have three tables to worry about :

cards,
categories and
cards2categories

This is because cards can belong to many categories

So I have placed in cards model (the foreign key is image)

```
public function categories(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Cards2Cat', 'image');
    }
```

In a controller I tried

```
$cards = DB::table('cards')->categories->get();
```

but it did not work.

My next problem will be that the card2cat will return a number rather than the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this use in your class declaration

```
use App\Cards; //or whatever is your model name
```

for the query try this

```
$cards = Cards::with('categories')->get();
```

then

```
foreach($cards as $card){

    //$card->categories will contain the array of all categories rows
    //associated with this card and you can loop through it.

    foreach($card->categories as $category){
        //do something maybe?
    }
}
```